# class template specialization with nondatatype template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have been trying with following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T, int SIZE>
class Stack
{
        T element;
        T size[SIZE];
        public:
        void  setElement (T elmt)
        {
                element  = elmt;
                cout <<"Inside setElement"<<endl;
        };
        Stack()
        {
                cout <<"Constructor "<<endl;
                cout <<" SIZE is "<<SIZE<<endl;
        }
};

// Int class Specialization.


template<>
class Stack<int>
{  int element;
        int size[SIZE];
        public:
        void  setElement (int elmt)
        {
                element  = elmt;
                cout <<"Inside setElement"<<endl;
        };

        Stack()
        {
                cout <<"Constructor "<<endl;
                cout <<" SIZE is "<<SIZE<<endl;
        }
}


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  Stack<float,50> s;
  Stack<int,20> s1;
}
```

I have specialized Stack template class to 'int' datatype.

But i do not know how to bring non-type template parameter 'int SIZE' inside the template while specialise template class?

I am getting below compilation error:

```
temp1.cpp:26:7: error: too few template arguments for class template 'Stack'
class Stack<int>
      ^
temp1.cpp:5:7: note: template is declared here
class Stack
      ^
temp1.cpp:44:1: error: cannot combine with previous '(error)' declaration specifier
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
^
temp1.cpp:44:5: error: no function template matches function template specialization 'main'
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `SIZE` template parameter on your specialization.

The template declaration should be :

```
template<int SIZE>
class Stack<int, SIZE>
```

---

Live demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dfcb34ecda144c0b).